# Function being equal on infinitely many points implies it's constant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, proof-explanation

I have the following problem and solution given in my textbook:

Does there exist a nonconstant function $f : (1,∞) → \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the relation $f(x)= f(\frac{x^2+1}{2} )$ for all $x>1$ and such that $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)$exists?

For $x>1$ deﬁne the sequence $(x_n)n≥0$ by $x_0 = x$ and $x_{n+1} = x^2_{n}+1/2$ , $n ≥ 0$. The sequence is increasing because of theAM–GM inequality. Hence it has a limit L, ﬁnite or inﬁnite. Passing to the limit in the recurrence relation, we obtain $L^2 -2L +1 = 0$ ; hence either $L =1$ or $L =∞$. Since the sequence is increasing, $L ≥ x0 > 1$, so $L =∞$. We therefore have $f(x)= f(x_0) = f(x_1) = f(x_2) =···= lim_{n→∞} f(x_n) = lim_{x→∞} f(x)$. This implies that $f$ is constant, which is ruled out by the hypothesis. So the answer to the question is negative.

I am having trouble with the last part, why does the values that the function takes on at a certain set of points imply it is constant for all points because in general, this is not true.

Comment: Wait nevermind I think I got it. It's because the limit is a fixed point of the recurrence right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $C=lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)$. You proved that for any $x$ in the domain of $f$, we have $f(x)=C$. And that is the *definition* of a constant function.

That's it. Job done!

It's possible that you lost sight of your progress because you start the proof with "For $x>1$" but you then reuse the letter $x$ as the variable in the limit. If you avoid reusing letters, you can avoid that sort of confusion.

Edit: Let me be clearer. I am not investigating whether a constant function satisfies the given relations. Obviously it does. I am describing what *you* have already proved.

Your proof starts with "For $x>1$", without making any further assumptions about $x$. This means that any conclusions you draw apply to all such $x$. You then prove the sequence of equations $f(x)= f(x_0) = f(x_1) = f(x_2) =···= \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$. In particular, the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side: $f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$. But the right-hand side is not a function of $x$; it is a constant. We can name this constant $C$. So you have successfully proved that $f(x)=C$ for all $x$. In other words, $f$ is a constant function.

In summary, you have proved that **if** $f$ satisfies the given relations, **then** it is constant. So the answer to the question is negative.

Comment: The problem asks for non-constant, obviously constant works.

Comment: To the proposer: The Q in your text is "Does there exist  a non-constant function such that ....?"   but  you had trouble understanding why the   correct answer is "No" and I think the first sentence of this A explains it.